# First entry in ResultSet

Tags: java, database, postgresql, prepared-statement, resultset

Hi I am trying to create a java form which displays results on a jtable. The connection is done ok however I am not getting the first entry.

```
void refreshdata()
{
    try {
       ConnectionDB condb = new ConnectionDB(driver, url, username, password);
       condb.getdata();
       rs = condb.rs;
       while(rs.next())
       {
         return_id = rs.getInt("id");
         return_notes = rs.getString("notes");
         Table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
         System.out.println(return_id+" | "+return_notes); //FOR TESTING ONLY
       }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(TestFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Can you please assist?

Thank you

Comment: however? should finish your sentence ;)

Comment: When you say not getting the first entry, do you mean its skipping the first entry or you're not getting any results at all?

Comment: yes sorry, finished it :)

Comment: Skipping first entry because it is displaying it in System.out.println(" ... ");

Comment: rs.next() is the problem...^^

Comment: Try something like do - while instead of while, when you call while, you use .next() that goes to the next record... and, at that point, you did not handle the record data... !

Answer (score 0):

you can grap the first element using

```
rs.first()
```

before you jump into your loop.

Comment: `if (rs.first()) { do { ... } while (rs.next()); }`

Answer (score 0):

Doing in the loop:

```
    Table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

implies that at the end just one model remains, containing the last record, or something weird.

Simply try:

```
  condb.getdata();
  rs = condb.rs;
  Table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
  rs.close();
```

Also statement and result set are not closed.